# How can I see who uses an NPM package on Github?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I would like to see how open-source projects use a particular NPM module.

Let's say I would like to find projects using the "normalizr" NPM package.

If I type "normalizr" into Github, I will get a bunch of forks and unrelated projects.

I really *just* want to see who has "normalizr" in their `package.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

You can see that on NPM website.

For example, go to [normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr), on right side look for [Dependents](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/normalizr) section where all the dependents are listed. From there you can find their respective github/other repository links. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a very good resource, and it's almost what I'm looking for.
I was really looking more for a tool to find software "projects" (opensource applications intended for end users) rather than NPM packages.

Comment: Does it include Private Repo as well?